# how to use where clause on the data return from when clause of the query

Tags: oracle, case-when

I have a query which looks something like this.

```
select case 
           when salary<5000
             then date1
           else date2
       end "app"
from employees
order by app desc;
```

Here I am printing date1 column's value if employee's salary is less than 5000 and date2 if his salary is greater than 5000. Now I want to apply a further filter on the date I am receiving from this query i.e. show only those record where returned date is in last 7 days. I can use the "app" synonym in order by clause but when i try to use it in where clause, it throws a compile time error. How can apply this filter.

Note: this query is to be executed in oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the whole expression in the where clause

```
SELECT CASE WHEN salary < 5000 THEN date1 ELSE date2 END "app" FROM employees
WHERE  CASE WHEN salary < 5000 THEN date1 ELSE date2 END >= SYSDATE - 7
ORDER  BY "app" DESC;
```

or use your original query as a subquery:

```
SELECT "app"
FROM   (SELECT CASE WHEN salary < 5000 THEN date1 ELSE date2 END "app" FROM employees)
WHERE  "app" >= SYSDATE - 7
ORDER  BY "app" DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the result using  where

```
select 
   case when salary<5000 then date1 else date2 end "app" 
from employees 
where case when salary<5000 then date1 else date2 end   >= sysdate -7
order by app desc;
```